# how to display a custom entity in a view

Tags: views

This is my first time making a custom module and I want to display some of the content that is produced in a view, but I can't figure out how to make my custom entity show up in the SHOW: select list when making a new view.

What code do I need to add to my custom module to have it show up there?

[image: View]

Comment: I'm pretty sure it was in views  documentation. Can't start looking now, to late night for me.

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/node/1208874

Comment: @Andrew I did my best to do what it said(as far as I understood), but my custom entity didn't show up in the list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include this in your hook_entity_info

```
MyModule_entity_info() {
...
'views controller class' => 'EntityDefaultViewsController',
...
}
```

For more details check this link : http://www.sitepoint.com/build-custom-drupal-entities/

Comment: Ok, thanks!
In the MyModule_entity_info() it has a base table field, do you know how to set up an entity that is built with two tables? (for example, a person who can select multiple values in a select list, so the person is stored in one table, and the selected values are stored by user_id in another table)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/build-custom-entities-drupal-setup/) and [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/build-custom-drupal-entities/) articles or download [Model Entities](https://www.drupal.org/project/model) module and look how new entity is implemented in this module.

Comment: A question on that,
In MyModule_entity_info() it has a base table field, but I can't figure out how to set up an entity with more than one table. 
Do you know how to set up an entity that is built with two tables? (for example, a person who can select multiple values in a select list, so the person is stored in one table, and the selected values are stored by user_id in another table)